# How to access Future values while debugging in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

**Please upvote:** https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/40198

I am wondering how I can get access to the value of a future, while debugging in vs-code? Right now i need to introduce another temp variable to get the debugger to await the statement. This is how I am accessing a value at the moment:

```
 Future<void> disconnect2() async {
    var conn = await isConnected;
    if (conn) await internalDisconnect();
  }
```

But I would like to write the following:

```
  Future<void> disconnect() async {
    if (await isConnected) await internalDisconnect();
  }
```

And still be able to access the value of `isConnected` with the debugger.

What I tried so far:

Try to add the expression `(await isConnected)` to the watch.
[image]
Tried to evaluate the expression `(await isConnected)` in the debug console.
[image]
Try to add the expression `isConnected` to the watch.
[image]
Tried to evaluate the expression `isConnected` in the debug console.
[image]
Tried to access the value through hovering over the instance. In the screenshot it is null, but most of the time I get to access only the future object.
[image]

Is there any easy way to access the value of a future while debugging?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot see the value of future value while it is not awaited and loaded. The reason for it, future type is waiting the data, so it reserve part of memory for future value. You can access it only after getting the value f.e. value from REST API.
You can use **then** method and see the value there.

```
someFuture(arg).then((erg) => print(erg));
```

Comment: Yes, thanks for your answer. I know what a future is, but there must be an easy way in vs code to get the value while debugging. In C# for example if you add a "Task" (equivalent to Future in Dart) into the watch it awaits them for you.